# pgfplots other tick labels than symbolic coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
        symbolic y coords={A},
        ytick={A}, % I want to have B here
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
    (1,{A})
    };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to have the tick label say `B` as a first step.
Entering `B` in the indicated spot throws:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `B' has not been defined mething like [normalized]B?. ]
```

If this is possible I want (as the second step) that the label says `B` with a nice circle around it which I draw elsewhere in my document with the macro:

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize] (char) {#1};}}
```

Typing `ytick={\circled{B}}` causes `pdfLaTeX` to hang.

Comment: `yticklabel` and `ytick` are different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here thanks to the hint given by @percusse. One needs to specify `symbolic y coords`, `ytick` **and** `yticklabels`. Not sure why though.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    symbolic y coords={{A},{C}},
    ytick={A,C},
    yticklabels={\circled{B1},\circled{B2}},
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
        (1,{A})
    };
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
        (2,{C})
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]